# Why numpy argmax() not getting the index?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, data-science

so I'm really new with data analysis and numpy library, and just playing around with the builtin function.

I have this on top of my file `import numpy as np`

```
new_arr = np.arange(25)
print new_arr.argmax()
```

which should print out the index of the maximum value, not the value it self. But it keeps on giving me 24.
As what I understand `max()` gives you the maximum value, while `argmax()` gives you the index of the maximum value.

Answer (score 0):

`np.arange` starts from zero (unless you give it a different start), and indexing is also 0-based.  So in `np.arange(25)`, the 0th element is zero, the 1th element is 1, etc.  So every element is the same number as its index.  So the maximum value is 24 and its index is also 24.

Comment: Thank you. sorry I wasn't really paying attention:)